# Is there an alchemist archetype that gets more or earlier discoveries?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm wanting to get discoveries as early as possible and as many as possible,

I'm willing to sacrifice other class features, is there a paizo-made archetype that does this?

I'm going for stuff like Vestigial arm, tentacle, going for a creepy vibe for a character build.

Comment: Which discoveries and to what end? (The site's pretty good at finding ways to accomplish specific goals, too!)

Comment: Vestigial arm, tentacle, going for a creepy vibe for a character build.

Comment: I’d be surprised if there is one, but very pleasantly surprised! Hoping to see a good answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly, there are ways to get that. As far as I know, those are the only ones:

A [Fey World Innovator](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/fey-world-innovator-alchemist-archetype/) have a certain number of point per day they can spend, one of those use is to add to their mutagen the effects of a discovery they don't have but meet the prerequisite for (only to select in a short list: feral mutagen, tentacle, vestigial arm, or wings)

An [Inspired Chemist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/inspired-chemist) can forfeit any discovery they take for two Investigator Talent that are only active while they are under cognatogen. Nothing stops them from using both those talents on [Alchemist Discovery](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/investigator-talents/paizo-investigator-talents/alchemist-discovery) (that can be taken multiple times).

A [Metamorph](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/metamorph-alchemist-archetype) gets the effects of Preserve Organs, so that's basically one more discovery (although for a very steep price).

A [Mnemostiller](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/mnemostiller-alchemist-archetype/) gets Infusion as a bonus discovery

A [Sacrament Alchemist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/sacrament-alchemist) gets basically a free slot for a temporary discovery she can change every day

On top of that, there is a number of ways to replace Mutagen at lvl1 with Cognatogen, so if you only care about this one it is a net bonus in the number of discoveries.

Comment: This answer is great (already +1), but it’d be really useful to indicate the levels at which you get the discoveries, since the goal (as I understand it) is to minimize the number of alchemist levels required to gain the desired discoveries.